# ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER Error when building a SQL Database Project in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

Added a VS2017 Database Project to my solution and started receiving the following error in my CI build using a hosted agent:

> (SPP-CreateDeployCommand target) ->  MSDEPLOY : error Code:
>   ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER [D:\a\1\s\myDatabase.csproj]
>   MSDEPLOY : error count: 1. [D:\a\1\s\myDatabase.csproj]

I have tried installing both the SSDT and ScriptDOM nuget packages but that didn't help.

You'll notice this error occurs on the compilation of .csproj project.  This is my deploy project where I have some MSBuild script to handle DACPAC creation and WebDeploy packaging.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? If so, you can share a sample project on the OneDrive. On the other hand, try to add command line task to build definition (Tool: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil`; Arguments: `/i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll"`

Comment: FYI - I get a different error on a VS2017 Hosted agent - ERROR_DACFX_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new database project?

Comment: https://github.com/rschiefer/DbDeployWithSqlDeploy.git

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with your project. Steps: 1. New build definition 2. Select repository 3. Select .NET Desktop build template 4. Remove Visual Studio Test and Publish symbols path tasks 5. Queue build with Hosted VS2017 agent. Can you share the log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true and queue build, then share this log)

Comment: Used a blank template, added Nuget restore and VS build task, and set build task to build the solution with MSBuild arg "/p:DeployOnBuild=true".

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the WebDeploy on your build agent is outdated. Please install [the latest version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43717) on your build agent, and don't GAC Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll. You should also update the WebDeploy on your target server (the machine where the application/database is deployed to) if possible.

Comment: I'm using the Hosted VS2017 agent in VSTS.

Comment: Where are you deploying your web application to? That machine needs to be updated with the latest WebDeploy.

Comment: Its not actually deploying in this build its only creating a Msdeploy package.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this issue with Hosted VS2017 agent and submit a feedback here: [Database project deploy throguh MSDeploy on Hosted agent error](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/201630/database-project-deploy-throguh-msdeploy-on-hosted.html).

It is working fine on my private agent, so you may setup a private agent on your machine.

Comment: Yes, I have a private agent setup as a temporary workaround and it works there.

Comment: @chief7 You can follow this issue here [ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER Error when building a SQL Database Project in VSTS](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/199631/error-scriptdom-needed-for-sql-provider-error-when.html).